# two ways of using symbolic solve in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mupad

Why can Matlab solve the following system of equations that way:

```
eq1 = 'x1+x2+x4=1';
eq2 = 'x3+x4 = 2';
eq3 = '2*x1+3*x2+1*x3+4*x4=3';
eq4 = '3*x1+4*x2+2*x3+6*x4=p';
[p a b c d] = solve(eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,p,x1,x2,x3,x4);
```

but not if I use the following code?

```
A = sym([1 1 0 1; 0 0 1 1; 2 3 1 4; 3 4 2 6]);
x = [x1 x2 x3 x4].';
b = sym([1 2 3 p].');
[p a b c d] = solve(A(1,:)*x==b(1),A(2,:)*x==b(2),A(3,:)*x==b(3),A(4,:)*x==b(4),p,x)
```

The first thing gives a value for p, and x1 to x4, while the second does not find any solution.

Thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R2012b neither of those work. One obtains warnings and, if anything, only parametrized solutions. You should check what you entered.

Why? First, `rank(A)` returns three, which means that you don't have four independent equations for your four-dimensional system. Second, even if you had four equations, you're trying to solve for five unknowns (`p` as well). You may need another constraint. Also note that the output of your calls to `solve` overwrites your symbolic variable `p`.

If you're trying to solve systems of symbolic equations, don't use `solve`, look into [`linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html). Or, you can solve for `p` and a subset of `x` with your non-full rank system:

```
x = sym('x',[4 1]);
syms p;
A = sym([1 1 0 1; 0 0 1 1; 2 3 1 4; 3 4 2 6]);
b = sym([1 2 3 p].');
[p_ x1 x2 x3] = solve(A*x==b,p,x(1),x(2),x(3)) % results will be function of x4
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake, R2013a can solve the first example, though it returns a warning and introduces an additional variable (which, as you say, is to be expected).

Comment: The warning for the second case indicates that MuPAD thinks that it has 8 equations. This because you passed in the vector `x` as a variable to solve for rather than `x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4)`.